# What's the difference between using 'export declare function' and 'export function' in a '.d.ts' file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I've seen in typescript declaration files people write decelerations like so:

`export function useTheme(): ITheme;`

But I was under the impression that the `declare` keyword was necessary for writing type decelerations for functions that are defined elsewhere?

If this is valid, and so is `export declare function useTheme(): ITheme;`, then is there any reason to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making it simple, in code if you want to create some declaration like you know some function exists globally but compiler doesn't know that - you use `declare` keyword. But definition file is a little different. As this is actually definition file, nothing else but declarations should be there hence these files treat all entities as declarations no matter that you used `declare` keyword or not. Using `declare` keyword there is just kind of convention which is obviously recommended as we shouldn't specify content type based on extension in that case. Here TypeScript compiler knows that `d.ts` is a declaration file but some other compiler may not